# Cassandra Consistency levels

Tags: cassandra

I just want to reduce the consistency level while retrying during an unavailability exception. My current configurations are.

```
   RF=8
   CL=QUORUM  ((8/2)+1)=5;
```

I have found only these levels,to where I can reduce it.

```
     ConsistencyLevel.THREE
     ConsistencyLevel.TWO
     ConsistencyLevel.ONE.
```

How can I give ConsistencyLevel level of 4 ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the `ConsistencyLevel` of 4.
CL 2 and 3 are amenities that should deal with most of situations.

If you have a RF of 8 and you can't get a quorum w/r operation due to unavailable exception it means you have at least 4 of the 8 nodes handling the token offline/unreachable. Rather than thinking about degrading the CL to 4 I'd just use a `ConsistencyLevel.THREE` and immediately fix the problem in the cluster.

HTH,
Cheers

Carlo